# why is username registered as null in database?

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-studio

I am currently working on an android app and I completed a register and login form for android.

The only Problem is that the username is always declared as a 0.

I hope you can understand me and can help me too!

[MySql output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ui1Bq.png)

php code:
http://textuploader.com/djedy

[EDIT]

android-studio code:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    final EditText etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
    final EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

    final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

    bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String name = etName.getText().toString();
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final int age = Integer.parseInt(etAge.getText().toString());
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if (success) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, username, age, password, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Can we see more of the code? You are requesting a POST but we only see you are asking for name.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the username as an integer value.

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $username, $age, $password);
```

My assumption is you want to bind your $age an interger value instead?

Try changing the above to this:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssis", $name, $username, $age, $password);
```

Hope this helps!

---

EDIT: Hopefully you are just testing and will implement this but you **NEED** to be hashing your passwords!

Please look into this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

And start using the **password_hash()** and **password_verify()** functions as part of your login/registration scripts.

Comment: siss => ssis. Im changing the interger bind to the age field and setting the username to a string bind.

Comment: Great answer! He changed the siss to ssis since you were saying username = integer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works fine! I wanted to hash the code later but its awesome that it works now!

Comment: now login doesnt work :/<br/>I posted php code for login here: https://jpst.it/15CQM <br/> The funny thing is when I login with my old saved Integer and password it works but now it doesnt happen anything when i click on button

Comment: [EDIT] I solved the problem by looking in the Android Monitor, "the String coul not be converted into int".